# How to check service status before executing asynctask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to execute a asynctask depending on the status of the webservice....if the web service is down then a toast will be displayed ....but it isn't working as i want....

```
ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo nIn = conMan.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            State s = nIn.getState();

            ServiceCheck sc = new ServiceCheck(MainActivity.this);

            if(s == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
            { 
                if(sc.isServiceOk())
                {
                   new Test().execute(file_url);
                }
            }
```

and this is where i am checking for the service status...

```
public class ServiceCheck {
private Context cntext;
    public ServiceCheck(Context context)
    {
        this.cntext = context;
    }

    public boolean isServiceOk()
    {   
        try
        {  
            ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) cntext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo nInf = conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if(nInf != null && nInf.isConnected())
            {
            URL url = new URL(file_url);
            HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            urlc.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            urlc.connect();

            if(urlc.getResponseCode() == 200)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(cntext, "Service Down", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //return false;
            }
        }
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: But i want to check it when button is pressed for retrieving data........

Answer (score 1):

you have to perform your isServiceOk() method in a background thread. From what you have posted, it looks like you are making this network call from the main thread and this will throw an exception. You would have to post the result of this method back to the main thread and then figure out if you want to proceed or not. If you delegate this method to a background thread, you can still use an Handler to post the Toast.

Again, inferring from what you posted, Test is your implementation of the AsyncTask. That portion is fine since I am assuiming your network operation is being performed from the background.

Bottom line is, one way or the other, your isServiceOk() method needs to be run from a background thread - either an AsyncTask or a normal Thread will do.